# What will be the domain of this function?

Tags: functions

Question: find the domain of the following function $g(x) = (x^2 - 6x)^{1/4}$

My try:

Since the expression $x^2 - 6x$ is under an even root, then the expression should be greater than or equal to zero, hence:

$x^2 - 6x \geq 0$

$\implies x(x - 6) \geq 0$

$\implies x \geq 0$ or $x \geq 6$

What am I doing wrong?

[The solution given in the website.](http://slader.com/textbook/9781305071759-precalculus-mathematics-for-calculus-7th-edition/157/exercises/67/)

[A similar problem](http://slader.com/textbook/9781305071759-precalculus-mathematics-for-calculus-7th-edition/157/exercises/68/)

Comment: look at page 13 of this http://www.arihantbooks.com/chapterdownloads/B015.pdf

Comment: It is sometimes easier to solve these problems by visualizing the graph rather than purely using algebra. How does the graph of $f(x) = x^2 - 6x$ look like? It is a concave-up parabola with zeroes at $x=0$ and $x=6$. The answer should be clear to you then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inequalities don't factor like that.

$a*b\geq 0$ does not mean ($a\geq 0$ or $b\geq 0$).

It means (($a\geq0$ and $b\geq0$) or ($a\leq 0$ and $b\leq 0$)).

Because two positive numbers multiplied together give a positive number, and two negative numbers multiplied together also give a positive number.

Comment: So, with that logic, I go for the 1st one and my answer should be correct.

Comment: That is a mathematical "or", [inclusive or](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_disjunction#Truth_table). You are asked to find the full domain, not just part of it.

Comment: Ah, okay, got it. So, the answer really would be $x \geq 6$ and $x \geq 0$ _or_ $x \leq 6$  and $x \leq 0$. Right?

Comment: Yes. That simplifies to $x\geq 6$ *or* $x\leq 0$, the answer given in your textbook.